# What datatypes are supported by Google App Engine's datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I know how to table in google BigTable.I have one doubt regarding this.what are all the datatype supported by google BigTable.

Comment: It may be helpful in the future if you set a more descriptive title, something that summarizes your question in a clearer way.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [Class and Field Annotations](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html#Class_and_Field_Annotations) section from [Using JPA with App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html):

> Fields of the data class that are to
>   be stored in the datastore must either
>   be of a type that is persisted by
>   default or expliclty declared as
>   persistent. You can find a chart
>   detailing JPA default persistence
>   behavior on [the DataNucleus website](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jpa/types.html).
>   To explicitly declare a field as
>   persistent, you give it an `@Basic`
>   annotation:
>
> ```
> import java.util.Date;
> import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
>
> import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.ShortBlob;
>
> // ...
>     @Basic
>     private ShortBlob data;
> ```
>
> The type of a field can be any of the
>   following:
>
> - one of the [core types](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Core_Value_Types) supported by the datastore
> - a Collection (such as a `java.util.List<...>`) of values of a
>     core datastore type
> - an instance or Collection of instances of a `@Entity` class
> - an embedded class, stored as properties on the entity

To define and use `Email` and `PhoneNumber` as data types, create entities for them and map them as [`@OneToOne`](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jpa/annotations.html#OneToOne) or make them [`@Embeddable`](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jpa/annotations.html#Embeddable).

Comment: How to define and  use email and phone number data type in big table

Comment: do you know if there is a limit to the size() of the Collection?

Answer (score 2):

David's answer above gives the list of datatypes supported natively by Appengine. But to write real-life applcations with GAE you need more datatypes and patterns supported. Besides JPA, JDO and LowLevel api with their limitations and associated issues are not that practical to use.

After trying them all we have chosen [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) and never looked back. It is a very efficient Data Access Abstraction layer specifically designed for GAE. Coming back to your question, it is very easy to add serialisers for your own datatypes with Objectify.

Update:
3 years after the original answer, I can say that Objectify is one of the best software library choices I made.

Answer (score 2):

The datatypes supported by Datastore are listed in

[**Datastore** > **Entities, Properties, and Keys** > **Properties and value types**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types) is the list of data types supported natively in App Engine for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Bigtable can store all Object types. Its just a giant key-value dictionary

Comment: I tried to store a GregorianCalendar and got an unsupported operation exception.

Comment: The question is confused. AppEngine may use BigTable as an implementation layer, but it doesn't expose that to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for a list of datatypes supported in GAE using JDO:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html

and using Python:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

The definitive way to find the supported low-level property types in Java is to use [DataTypeUtil](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DataTypeUtils)

e.g.

```
if (!DataTypeUtil.isSupportedType(value.getClass())) {
  // Convert the value to a supported type.
}
```